# How to fix AndroidX compatibility for Flutter in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, compilation, androidx

I'm getting this error when trying `flutter build apk` :

```
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
*******************************************************************************************
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

But I can make my code run directly on a phone or an emulator...
I already created APK files with that project (and sent it to the stores). The last APK was created on 2019/07/17. Since then, I only added some data in lists.

I already tried to compile in the same conditions than the last time then :

- `flutter clean`, etc.;
- Invalidating caches;
- Downgrade Flutter version;
- Downgrade Kotlin version;
- Downgrade Gradle version;
- Downgrade Gradle-wrapper's distribution URL.

Here are my dependencies :

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: any
  firebase_auth: any
  google_sign_in: ^3.2.4
  flutter_datetime_picker: 1.0.7
  numberpicker: any
  flutter_svg: any
  dio: any
  path_provider: any
  firebase_messaging: any
  charts_flutter: any
  barcode_scan: 1.0.0
  unity_ads_flutter: any
  progress_indicators:
```

Gradle files :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**[EDIT] I changed my computer. Might it be the issue reason ?**

**[EDIT 2] SOLVED**

Steps:

- Upgrade packages

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: any
  firebase_auth: any
  google_sign_in: any
  flutter_datetime_picker: 1.0.7
  numberpicker: any
  flutter_svg: any
  dio: any
  path_provider: any
  firebase_messaging: any
  charts_flutter: any
  barcode_scan: 1.0.0
  unity_ads_flutter: any
  progress_indicators:
```

- Copy all files in new project

It looks like some files were corrupted or lost during transfers to my new computer

Comment: Have you followed this guide https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Comment: "The failure ***may have been*** because ..". You should find the actual Gradle error by running the task with `--info`.

Comment: @F-1 : I followed the guide and looked for the most recent versions of implementations I needed on AndroidX's site.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot : No problem has been shown. Only warnings with automatically replaced obsolete calls

Comment: @BarracudApps The Gradle errors are not shown when executing `flutter build`. You will have to manually debug the failing Gradle tasks. There should be enough information out there if you did not understand what I mean.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot : I tried `./gradlew tasks --info`

Comment: @BarracudApps I cannot debug it for you, but `gradlew assembleRelease --info` would be a start..

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot : Sorry, I'm tired --' It showed that the problem comes from `google_sign_in`
```
> Task :google_sign_in:verifyReleaseResources FAILED
Caching disabled for task ':google_sign_in:verifyReleaseResources' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':google_sign_in:verifyReleaseResources' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has failed previously.
All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':google_sign_in:verifyReleaseResources'.
Unable do incremental execution: full task run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading a lot on internet [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11113) y foud everyone solves this problem by upgrading libraries. I found there is a lot of recent versions of google_sign_in so try upgrading google_sign_in to 4.0.6

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, after a week of searching and mixing some of the answers I found, this was the one that finally worked

Follow the guide in: https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan
But do this modifications:

Edit your project-level build.gradle file to look like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.30'
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
...
```

Edit your app-level build.gradle file to look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
...

dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
...
}
```

And if when you compile the app says something about a difference between androidx appcompat 1.0.0 and 1.0.2
Go to your plugin build.gradle file and change on dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
...
}
```

Comment: I just tried to downgrade Kotlin version as you recommend but nothing changed. I seems like the problem comes from google_sign_in

Comment: I had this problem was when I add to my flutter proyect the location plugin and upgrade the core to flutter 1.5.4. But can fix it whit those steps.

Answer (score 1):

Update your gradle.properties file with this:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
```

Comment: Try to use fixed plugins resolution... there are some of those plugins that are pre AndroidX:
• cloud_firestore: 0.8.2+3
• firebase_auth: 0.7.0
• google_sign_in: 3.2.4
• path_provider: 0.4.1
• firebase_messaging: 2.1.0
maybe with 'any' you are resolving a version of a plugin that doen't uses AndroidX

Comment: Look here from the documentation: [link] (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility)
"AndroidX can break a Flutter app at compile time in two ways:
    * The app uses an AndroidX plugin and its main build.gradle file has a compileSdkVersion below version 28.
    * The app uses both deprecated and AndroidX code at the same time. These problems must be fixed by either manually migrating the code to the same library, or downgrading to versions of the plugins that still use the original support libraries"

Comment: Nothing changes with fixed versions. Since now, I had no problem with `any` packages